HTML services won't work as they are in a library
I am very new to google apps script. I have a container bound script that works so I wanted to share it as a library. The problem is that after sharing it as a library, it doesn't function as it should be. Checked the console and I am getting this error
Uncaught TypeError: google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(...).processForm is not a function
Library
Code.gs
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function processForm(data) {
  // Get the active spreadsheet and the sheet named 'Sheet1'
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  
  // Get the header row (first row) from the sheet
  const headerRow = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  
  // Find the column that has "acreage" in the header
  let acreageColumnIndex = -1; // Default value if the header is not found
  for (let i = 0; i < headerRow.length; i++) {
    if (headerRow[i].toLowerCase().includes("acreage")) {
      acreageColumnIndex = i + 1; // Convert to 1-based index for Google Sheets
      break; // Stop searching once we find the correct column
    }
  }
  
  // If no "acreage" header is found, throw an error
  if (acreageColumnIndex === -1) {
    throw new Error("Header with the word 'acreage' not found.");
  }

  // Get the submitted data from the form
  const minRanges = data.minRange; // Array of min range values
  const maxRanges = data.maxRange; // Array of max range values
  const values = data.value; // Array of values to be inputted

  // Get all the values in the "acreage" column, starting from the second row
  const numRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1; // Total number of rows, excluding the header row
  const acreageValues = sheet.getRange(2, acreageColumnIndex, numRows, 1).getValues(); // Get all values in the "acreage" column

  // Loop through each range that the user submitted in the form
  for (let i = 0; i < minRanges.length; i++) {
    const minRange = parseFloat(minRanges[i]); // Minimum range value
    const maxRange = parseFloat(maxRanges[i]); // Maximum range value
    const inputValue = values[i]; // Value to be inserted if the range matches

    // Check if both minRange and maxRange are valid numbers
    if (!isNaN(minRange) && !isNaN(maxRange)) {
      // Loop through all the "acreage" values and check if they fall within the range
      for (let j = 0; j < acreageValues.length; j++) {
        const acreage = parseFloat(acreageValues[j][0]); // Get the acreage value from the current row

        // If the acreage value is within the range (inclusive), set the value in the cell next to it
        if (!isNaN(acreage) && acreage >= minRange && acreage <= maxRange) {
          sheet.getRange(j + 2, acreageColumnIndex + 1).setValue(inputValue); // j + 2 because rows start from 2 (excluding header)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



function showForm() {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
    .setWidth(100) // Adjust the width for the sidebar
    .setHeight(600); // You can set a height, but it’s generally not needed for a sidebar
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html); // Show the sidebar instead of modal dialog
}



function onOpen(e){
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("Custom Menu")
  .addItem("Open Form", 'showForm')
  .addToUi();
}



Index.HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px;
      }
      h2 {
        text-align: center;
        color: #333;
      }
      .form-container {
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
      table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
      th, td {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      th {
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        color: #333;
      }
      input[type="text"] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 5px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
      input[type="button"] {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        border: none;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        font-size: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 5px;
      }
      input[type="button"]:hover {
        background-color: #45a049;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="form-container">
      <h2>Input Ranges Form</h2>
      <form id="rangeForm">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Min Range</th>
              <th>Max Range</th>
              <th>Value</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <!-- Creating five rows for input -->
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="minRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="maxRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="value" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="minRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="maxRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="value" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="minRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="maxRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="value" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="minRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="maxRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="value" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="minRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="maxRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="value" required></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="minRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="maxRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="value" required></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="minRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="maxRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="value" required></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="minRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="maxRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="value" required></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="minRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="maxRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="value" required></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
              <td><input type="text" name="minRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="maxRange" required></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="value" required></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="handleSubmit()">
      </form>
    </div>

    <script>
      function handleSubmit() {
        const formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('rangeForm'));
        const data = {};
        
        // Group form data by name
        formData.forEach((value, key) => {
          if (!data[key]) {
            data[key] = [];
          }
          data[key].push(value);
        });

        // Pass the grouped data to Google Apps Script function
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(() => {
            alert("Values submitted successfully!");
          })
          .processForm(data);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Container bound
Code.gs
function onOpen(e) {
 test()
}


function test(e){
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Custom Menu')
  menu.addItem("Open Form", 'Automation.showForm')
  menu.addToUi();
}

I tried searching on what was the cause and I read that HTML services on a library has an extra step but I couldn't wrap my head around it.

Shouldn't it be Automation.processForm like, google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(...)["Automation"]["processForm"]() or google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(...)["Automation.processForm"]()

Although I'm not sure about your expected result, as a simple modification, how about adding const processForm = e => Automation.processForm(e) into "Code.gs" of "Container bound"? By this, when google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(,,,).processForm(data) is run, this Automation.processForm is run through processForm. If this was not your expected result, I apologize.

Please add a [mcve]. Start by removing the doGet function as it "belongs" to a web application, and the onOpen function as it's a reserved name to be used for simple triggers on bound script, not a library. Include the bound script manifest, appsscript.json.
